# Keeping default listView onClick animation when color changed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I very much like the responsive "flooding" of a ListView row when you click on it; however, that effect disappears once you apply a color to a row (even when changing alpha levels). Once you change the color of the row, clicks will have no visual feedback attached to the ListView row.

Is there any way to retain this feature without programming it in? If not, what kind of workaround will I need?

## This is what I would like:

[image: Here is an example of what I mean]